# Is it possible to render a histogram without vertical line artifacts?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

As can be seen in the screenshot below, I have plotted a histogram with Matplotlib. On close inspection it can be seen that there are slight vertical line artifacts.

There could be a number of causes.

1. The PDF rendering in VS Code causes the artifacts, and other PDF readers produce different rendering effects
2. PDF format is the cause, and other export formats do not display the same effect
3. The artifacts are cause by Matplotlib, due to some missing configuration or options
4. Transparency

[image: Matplotlib Histogram]

---

In order to test (1.) I downloaded the pdf file from my Linux server to the same Laptop I am running the instance of VS Code from.

I opened it with Microsoft Edge browser, and saw the same effect, if not more noticable. See below screenshot.

*It looks quite clearly to be a problem cause by individual histogram bars being rendered or painted as individual blocks rather than some continuous shape. This might be an intrinsic limitation of how scalable vector graphics primatives are drawn.*

[image]

---

In order to test (2.), I tried exporting to another vector format. `eps`. I compared this file format on the Linux system instead of Windows (Windows doesn't appear to support eps, at least I couldn't open it with any of the programs I currently have installed).

I found that:

- eps doesn't appear to support transparency
- I did not see any artifacts, but this could be due to the lack of transparency

---

In order to test (.4), I turned transparency off, returned to using pdf format, and found that the artifacts were still present, and indeed more noticable than before.

---

**My question is what is causing these artifacts, and how can I produce a figure using matplotlib which does not cause the vertical line artifacts?**

Comment: None of the linked questions answer this question. One suggests to use a vector graphics format, which I have done here already. The other is again only relevant to raster formats.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was indeed related to a matplotlib configuration option.

It is possible to resolve the issue using this configuration option:

```
histtype='stepfilled'
```

I happened to find it as an example on this webpage:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/histogram_histtypes.html

Quite why this isn't the default I am not exactly sure.

Here is an example usage:

```
(bin_counts, bin_edges, _) = ax.hist(likelihood_values, bins, histtype='stepfilled') #, alpha=0.5
```

**Note:** I suspect the artifacting is only seen when the number of bins is large. In my case it was 100.